# Context2D.putImageData doesn't work

Tags: qt, canvas, qml

I am trying to push pixels on a QtQuick Canvas

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        width: 500
        height: 500
        Component.onCompleted:loadImage('kde.png');
        onImageLoaded:requestPaint();
        onPaint:{
            var ctx = getContext("2d");
            if (canvas.isImageLoaded('kde.png')) {
                var im = ctx.createImageData('kde.png');
                im.data[3] = 128;
                ctx.putImageData(im, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but nothing happens, the canvas stays blank.

The issue isn't with code execution or image loading, as `console.log` inside the `if` works, and inspecting `im.data` contents shows that it contains data. The issue seems to be that `putImageData` does nothing. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to debug `putImageData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure out why, but it seems that [`Context2D.putImageData()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#putImageData-method) is not the right tool and that [`Context2D.drawImage()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#drawImage-method-3) should be used instead.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        width: 500
        height: 500
        Component.onCompleted:loadImage('kde.png');
        onImageLoaded:requestPaint();
        onPaint:{
            var ctx = getContext("2d");
            if (canvas.isImageLoaded('kde.png')) {
                var im = ctx.createImageData('kde.png');
                im.data[3] = 128;
                ctx.drawImage(im, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

works as expected.

Comment: Correct. `.createImageData` is meant for pixel manipulation rather than simply drawing an image on the canvas. To do that, just use `drawImage` and there's no need for createImageData / putImageData

Comment: @markE Pixel manipulation is what I actually do, the image drawing was just to provide an easier MWE (without `ImageData` indexation fiddling), but the results are the same: `drawImage` works, `putImageData` doesn't.

Comment: See also related bugs [QTBUG-62280](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62280) and [QTBUG-53770](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53770).